# Does there exists a comparison sort such that no element is compared n-1 times?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

Imagine me and a bunch of my friends are trying to rank a bunch of rocks by weight, and at each time-step, each of us can pick up two rocks and announce to the group which one is heavier, and we only have n-2 time steps. Or maybe I am the only one doing the rock-weighing, but the rocks have the magical property that after being lifted up n-2 times, they spontaneously combust.

Can I always sort the list? If so how? If not why not?

(We can assume there are no equal elements.)

I played around a bunch with merge sort, insertion/selection sort, timsort, and odd-even parallel sort, but was always able to find an example that would require an element to be compared to every other element.

Comment: Sound like a description for a homework, but indeed very interesting. For me it sounds like you are looking for a Distributed Sorting Algorithms or Non-comparsion sorts. "_require an element to be compared to every other element._", not if a modified bucket sort is used.

Comment: You could start reading with something like [Distributed Sorting Algorithms](https://brunomaga.github.io/Distributed-Sort), then specifically [Non-comparsion sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Non-comparison_sorts) like [Bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort). Also [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) and [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Comment: [The answer is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). For 2,3, or 4 elements, the answer is definitely no.

Comment: If your `n` is sufficiently large (let say >100 to be safe), a bitonic sort should operate in `O(n log² n)` and unlike mergesort, the merge part should not compare 1 item to all others in pathological cases (for small `n` this can be the case due to the additional `log n` overhead and the hidden constant). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter (it seems to be fine for n=16 already). I think you can use the worst-case "parallel" performance to write a proof of that.